# Saving a draft mailing and sending a test message is very slow?

Tags: mariadb

It takes about 130s to send a test message

- No other queries are running on the database
- Mariadb 10.5.13-1

join_buffer_size=2M
key_buffer_size=28M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=1G

The server has 20GB ram.

170k records in civicrm_mailing_recipients

CiviCRM 5.66
CiviMail: Version 5.66.0
Mosaico: Version 3.2.1691060437

```
Query   |   76 | Sending data | INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_recipients (mailing_id, contact_id, email_id)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 130s! Where is your server located? On the moon!? (if so, you may need to enable the Lunar Module )

Comment: Sadly it is just down the road. 12ms.  Surely the data from 'insert into..' isn't blocking.